# Bootstrap Typeahead Repeat Search and Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm using the bootstrap typeahead plugin to to search through a list of terms and display the image of that term when selected.

Basic functionality works, but I have two issues:

1.) When a term is searched twice, the image does not show up the second time (assuming the updater function does not handle the same search twice?)

2.) Can I make it so that multiple images show up when searched (i.e, when a user types the letter "a", all the images associated with the terms that show up...are also visible)? I don't want a user to have to wait til a single choice is selected.

Thanks for the help (I'm a JS noob, so let me know if I need to clarify my questions further!)

```
var array = $('.test').data('array');
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
      items:4,
      source: array,
      updater: function(item){
         var pic = $('img[name="'+item+'"]').css('visibility','visible').css('display','inline');
         $('#search').empty().append(pic);
         return item;
      }
});
```